# Buttons loads index file on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```js
$(function() {
  /*declare a function call hAddCoin with parameter hValue for value and option for option +,x2,clear or max*/
  function hAddCoin(hValue, option) {
    var bet = document.getElementById('coincredits'); /*get the element*/
    var coins = document.getElementById('coins').innerHTML; /*get the inner of id coins*/
    var cur = parseInt(bet.value); /*get the coincredit and convert to integer*/
    var res = 0; /*declare res variable for result*/
    /*we need to check bet is empty or not*/
    if (typeof bet.value === "undefined" || bet.value == "") {
      cur = 0;
    }
    /*cek the option, it's will be +, X2 or max and default to 0*/
    switch (option) {
      case 1:
        {
          res = cur + hValue;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        {
          res = cur * option;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        {
          res = parseInt(coins);
        }
        break;
      default:
        {
          res = 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    bet.value = res; /*set value coin creadit to result*/
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="coincredits" id="coincredits" class="form-control" required="" parsley-type="text" placeholder="Minimum 10 coins" data-parsley-id="40" style="text-align:center; color: ;">
<div class="content" style="text-align:center;">
  <button id="clear" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(0,0)">Clear</button>
  <button id="add10" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(10,1,)">+10</button>
  <button id="add100" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(100,1)">+100</button>
  <button id="add1000" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(1000,1)">+1000</button>
  <button id="double" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(0,2)">x2</button>
  <button id="max" class="box-btn" onclick="hAddCoin(0,3)">Max</button>
</div>
```

It adds (or should add) value to the input field, but it just sends me to mywebsite.com/index.php

I have tried defrient scripts but this is happening every time. It gives me no errors and logs nothing in the console.

I know it might be a piece of cake but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: try removing  $( function () {.... from the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` elements are implicitly `type="submit"` which means they submit the form they reside in. If your `<form>` doesn't have an `action` attribute it will use the current page as target URL, which reloads the page.

You need to either explicitly set `type="button"` on each button or add an `onsubmit` event handler on the form that invokes `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Let's say i have two pages, index.php and page.php The buttons are on page.php but it goes to index.php. Is it still The same case?

Comment: If it loads a different page that means the `action` is set to something, if it's directed to your index.php my guess would be that it's `action="/"`.